# Drop down list show all elements but disabled for selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

I have JSP page and drop down list programatically populated.
Now, under some circumstances that dropdown should be disabled, but user should be still able to see all of it's element, but can't actually select it, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nenadbulatovic/6g4pmmpv/1/

```
<select>
  <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
  <option disabled value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option disabled value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option disabled value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option disabled value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Obviously as there is condition I can't just put disable next option.

This is actual part of code (drop down) where I need that.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <label><%=Constants.REQUIRED%>&nbsp;<c:out value="${requestScope.RESOURCES_MAP.SITE_PARENT}"/>:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100px" id="siteParentNameSelect" style="width:250px;margin-bottom:0px;">
          <option value=''>${requestScope.RESOURCES_MAP[SELECT]}</option>
          <c:forEach var="siteParentName" items="${siteParentNameList}">
            <option value="${(pageContext.request, siteParentName.id)}" ${siteParentName.id == '0' ? 'selected = "selected" ' : ''}> ${siteParentName.name}</option>
          </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I should check if some condition like "enabledFlag" and then if it is true/false enable/disable its elements for selection.

EDIT: I can use only JSP/JSTL, JavaScript, JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Angular `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<select>
  <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
  <option ng-disabled=flag value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option ng-disabled=flag value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option ng-disabled=flag value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option ng-disabled=flag value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

*For more info:* https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-disabled.asp

**EDIT:**

Unfortunatelly, I am not quite familiar with JSTL, but can't you do something like this?

```
<option value="mercedes" <c:if test="${flag}"><c:out value="disabled='disabled'"/></c:if>">
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't use AngularJS, we use jQuery